# How to support multiple games in a gamecenter app

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

I'm implementing a bundle app consisting of several games. I want to add multiplayer support through gamecenter to each and every game, and right now I started implementing multiplayer for one of them which is going good. But every time I sent a request to a friend or automatch, it is paired up with another device who is using the same app not necessarily the same game in my app. A similar thing should apply to apps with different multiplayer modes (deathmatch, goal run etc) so I guess it is possible. How can I differentiate multiplayer requests of users in gamecenter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [GKMatchRequest's playerGroup property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchRequest_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKMatchRequest/playerGroup) to match only against players using the same game mode (in your case, game).

> If your game sets the playerGroup property, only players whose requests share the same playerGroup value are automatched by Game Center.

Comment: I was not expecting such a simple solution. Tack tack!